# Nginx redirect to Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, nginx

I want to redirect a URL e.g domain.com/api/ to a specific Node.js server, the root URL shows my website. At the moment I use this config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3031/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
}
```

but it does not work.

What has gone wrong?

Thanks for help and best regards :)

Comment: try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the proxy_pass line

Comment: the direct ip has the same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fogot closing bracket after location /api section.
Your config working at my machine.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3031/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
  }
```

Also your nodejs backend must handle '/api' requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful!

Comment: how to do in case nodejs doesn't handle /api?

Comment: Use rewrite at nginx, it will rewrite original URL and pass another to upstream app `rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `proxy_pass` directive gets argument for backend and **optional URI**.

That means `proxy_pass http://localhost:3031;` will get the URI from the user, e.g `/api/res.json` so final URL for the NODE JS is: `http://localhost:3031/api/res.json`

But when you provide the URI to the directive itself, it overrides the requested URI in the **matching location**. e.g `location /api` and `proxy_pass http://localhost:3031/;` (note the suffixed slash). so the part `/api` is replaced by `/` and final URL is: `http://localhost:3031/res.json`.

from the NGINX docs:

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
> }
> ```

So it's important to understand that the part of the requested URI `/name/` is **replaced** by `/remote/` and then the rest of the requested URI is added to the final sent URI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful!